# TSQL - replace isnumeric = 0

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, isnumeric

I have a select statement and in that select statement I have a few columns on which I perform basic calculations (e.g.  [Col1] * 3.14). However, occasionally I run into non-numeric values and when that happens, the whole stored procedure fails because of one row.

I've thought about using a `WHERE ISNUMERIC(Col1) <> 0`, but then I would be excluding information in the other columns.

Is there a way in TSQL to somehow replace all stings with NULL or 0??

Comment: Save some possible headaches by using TRY_CAST() instead of ISNUMERIC().

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers the question *nobody* wants the answer to - "can this string be converted to at least one of the numeric data types, I don't care which ones specifically?". So, great. The fact that you want a `decimal` and the string can be converted to only the `money` type has really moved things forward for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer Try_Cast:

```
SELECT
    someValue
    ,TRY_CAST(someValue as int) * 3.14     AS TRY_CAST_to_int
    ,TRY_CAST(someValue as decimal) * 3.14 AS TRY_CAST_to_decimal
    ,IIF(ISNUMERIC(someValue) = 1, someValue, null) * 3.14 as IIF_IS_NUMERIC
FROM (values 
    ( 'asdf'), 
    ( '2' ),
    ( '1.55')
) s(someValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
SELECT blah1, blah2, blah3
   CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Col1) = 1 THEN [Col1] * 3.14 ELSE NULL END as whatever
FROM your_table
```

A case can also be made that..

- The non-numeric values should be converted to numeric or NULL if that's what's expected in the column, and
- If numbers are expected then the column should be a numeric data type in the first place and not a character data type, which allows for these types of errors.

Comment: `insert into your_table (blah1,blah2,blah3,Col1) values (1,2,3,'$4.0')` and try this and you'll still get an error - one example of the poorness of `ISNUMERIC`.

Answer (score 0):

`ISNUMERIC` is a terrible way to do this, as there are far too many things that identify as `NUMERIC` which are not able to be multiplied by a non-`MONEY` data type.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/

This fails miserably, as '-' is a numeric...

```
DECLARE @example TABLE (numerics VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @example VALUES ('-')

SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(numerics) = 1 THEN numerics  * 3.14 ELSE NULL END  
FROM @example;
```

Try `TRY_CAST` instead (albeit amend your DECIMAL precision to suit your needs):

```
DECLARE @example TABLE (numerics VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @example VALUES ('-')

SELECT TRY_CAST(numerics AS decimal(10,2)) * 3.14  FROM @example;
```

Comment: "there are far too many things that identify as NUMERIC which are not." -  not true. Anything that causes `ISNUMERIC` to return 1 can be converted to *at least one of the numeric data types*. The problem is, we don't care about such a nebulous possibility - we care about whether it can be converted to a *specific* numeric data type, and that's not the question that `ISNUMERIC` answers. E.g. `select CONVERT(money,'-')` is a perfectly valid conversion. But you don't care because you're not planning to convert your `'-'` to the `money` data type.

Answer (score 0):

trycast will test for a specfic type

```
declare @T table (num varchar(20));
insert into @T values ('12'), ('3.14'), ('5.6E12'), ('$120'), ('-'), (''), ('cc'), ('aa'), ('bb'), ('1/5'); 
select t.num, ISNUMERIC(t.num) as isnumeric
     , isnull(TRY_CONVERT(smallmoney, t.num), 0) as smallmoney 
     , TRY_CONVERT(float, t.num) as float
     , TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,4), t.num) as decimal 
     , isnull(TRY_CONVERT(smallmoney, t.num), TRY_CONVERT(float, t.num)) as mix
from @T t

num                  isnumeric   smallmoney            float                  decimal
-------------------- ----------- --------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------------------
12                   1           12.00                 12                     12.0000
3.14                 1           3.14                  3.14                   3.1400
5.6E12               1           0.00                  5600000000000          NULL
$120                 1           120.00                NULL                   NULL
-                    1           0.00                  NULL                   NULL
                     0           0.00                  0                      NULL
cc                   0           0.00                  NULL                   NULL
aa                   0           0.00                  NULL                   NULL
bb                   0           0.00                  NULL                   NULL
1/5                  0           0.00                  NULL                   NULL
```

interesting the last still fails